# Updating value from another table, but with a different value for the JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

What is the best way to update column myAmountColumn in myTable based on the sum of Amount column in myOtherTable joining on columns portfolio and security, except when 
myTable.portfolio = 'ABC', I want to join it to myOtherTable.portfolio = '123'.

Thank you.

This is the intended result in myTable, and sample data in myOtherTable:

```
myTable
Portfolio   Security        myAmountColumn
ABC         A               1000                       --> this is from 
                                     myOtherTable.Amount where Portfolio = '123'
DEF         B               2000                       --> this is from 
                                     myOtherTable.Amount where Portfolio = 'DEF'

myOtherTable 
Portfolio   Security    Amount
123         A           1000
DEF         B           2000
```

The below query gets an error

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 704

String or binary data would be truncated.

The statement has been terminated.

```
update j
set myAmountColumn =
  (
   select sum 
     (
       abs(convert(float,c2.Amount))
      )
    from      myOtherTablec2
    where   c2.portfolio = 
      CASE WHEN j.portfolio = 'ABC' THEN '123'
      ELSE j.portfolio
      END                       
    and c2.pta_security = j.tab_security
    ),
    CommentsColumn = CommentsColumn + ' my comments'
 from      myTable j, myOtherTablec
 where   c.portfolio = 
     CASE WHEN j.portfolio = 'ABC' THEN '123'
     ELSE j.portfolio
     END 
   and c.pta_security = j.tab_security
```

Comment: Hi, i included the sample data above and the intended result. Thank you

Comment: Try doing a select on the data you want to get the desired results, then work on converting to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the only piece you're missing:

```
WHERE myOtherTable.portfolio=CASE
  WHEN myTable.portfolio = 'ABC' THEN '123'
  ELSE myTable.portfolio
END
```

Although I use "WHERE" this could also be in the ON clause of a JOIN.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the query (and my original post), and i am getting the error "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 704
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: This is a data-related error.. not syntax.  looking at your query, I'd guess you're trying to add too many characters to the `CommentsColumn` column.

Comment: You are correct. Because I ran the query before, and comments were set before, and now i am appending to it. 
Thank you sooo much for your help !